# Taking two integer arguments (the first smaller than the second) print out lines between the two integer arguments

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a list of the most common passwords and their frequencies . It is a long list and it is formatted as such:

```
59462 password
49992 iloveyou
33919 princess
...   
30    yahoo123
```

To be clear, the most common password (according to this list) is "password" and 59,462 people have this password. The second most common password is "iloveyou" and it's frequency is 49,992.

**The problem is to take two integer inputs, the first one should be smaller than the second one (which the script should check for). The script should print all passwords with a frequency of at least the first number and at
most the second.**

I've been stuck on this problem for about 4 hours-ish and I'm completely lost.

This is what I've got so far:

```
var1=$1
var2=$2
if 
  [ $one -lt $two ]
then
  cat /home/misc/gwrika/cse251/hw3/short-rockyou.txt | awk '^$var1' | 
else
  echo "please enter the first argument as the smaller number and the second argument as the larger number"
fi
```

I'm honestly not even sure how to begin.

Answer (score 1):

I might approach it like this:

```
low=$1
high=$2
if [ "$low" -lt "$high" ]
then
  awk -v low="$low"-v high="$high" '$1 >= low && $1 <= high { print substr($0, index($0, " ")+1) }' /home/misc/gwrika/cse251/hw3/short-rockyou.txt
else
  echo "please enter the first argument as the smaller number and the second argument as the larger number"
fi
```

I renamed your variables, but the crux of it is a simple awk script where you pass in the low & high limits then ask if column 1 is in that range; if so, it prints the second field (by finding the position of the first space and skipping over it). If, as in your sample input of `30    yahoo123` you have multiple spaces separating the frequency from the password, but the passwords all begin at a certain column, use:

```
awk ... print substr($0, 7) ...
```

to begin printing at the appropriate column.

Comment: Minor issue with whitespace in passwords...